# When create nw.js app, could I not include chromium in it?

Tags: nw.js

Could I use Chromium as dependency? My codebase about 1MB, with resources 2MB, all project less than 10MB, but bundled it's about 100MB. If I want to use a few my apps, each will be 100MB!
Since a lot of people has Chrome or Chromium-based browsers, could it be done as dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the chrome lib is hooked with node.js in nwjs so its basically not a standard Chromium runtime.